# ¿Como hacer una enumeración de enumeraciones en C#?

Tags: c#, enum

Estoy intentado hacer una enumeración de enumeraciones (si fuese posible). Por el momento no lo he conseguido.

Lo he intentado hacer asi:

```
public enum Property { get, lost, update };
public enum Evento { public Property live, public Property heatlh, public Property money };
```

Y también lo he intentado hacer asi:

```
public enum Evento { public enum live { get, lost, update },
                     public enum heatlh { get, lost, update },
                     public enum Money { get, lost, update },
                  };
```

Ninguna de las dos formas funciona.

Lo que quiero hacer con esto es manejarlo en un switch dentro de una clase con funciones virtuales

Es decir desde alguna parte del código envio la señal de que se ha producido un evento. El identificador del evento es la propia enuneración. Algo así es lo que quiero hacer:

```
EnviarEvento(Evento.live.lost);//se perdió una vida
```

Y luego manejar ese evento usando un swtich tal que asi:

```
void ManejarEento(Evento tipo)
{
      switch(tipo)
      {
       case Evento.live.lost:
            OnLiveLost();
            break;
        default:
           break;
       } 
}


public virtual OnLiveLost()
{
  //manejar este vento
}
```

Ya sé que una una enumración no es mas que una sucesión de números enteros... pero me sería muy útil si hubiese alguna forma de estructurarlos de esa forma.

¿Alguien sabría como hacer algo asi si es posible?
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: No le veo sentido a lo que dices, además no creo que pueda hacerse, una enumeración es un dato atómico, es decir un solo valor

Comment: El sentido es no confundir los eventos ya que si los pongo por separado por ejemplo (live.get=0) y (heatlh.get=0) entonces el swith no funcionaria o los confundiría y sabria cal es cual... por eso quiero hacer una especia de matriz. Algo asi    Evento[0][0]=live.get, Evento[0][1]=live.lost... algo asi creo que funcionaría...

Comment: Algo me dice, que solo necesitas 2 enumeraciones, y una clase que las englobe. No existen enum de enum, porque los enum en realidad son wrappers de condiciones numericas... por mas que vos escribas palabras, son indices...

Comment: o mucho mejor, necesitas que esos enum sean binarios, de tal forma de poder combinarlos y pasarlos como si fueran uno solo...

Comment: ¿Como se hace eso?

Comment: Creo que al final voy a enviar el evento y la pripiedad por separado... lo malo de eso es que voy a tener que hacer un montón de switch en vez de uno solo... pero creo que va a ser lo menos lioso... Gracias por vuestra ayuda chicos!!

Comment: Podrias hacer una base evento, para sobreescribir la funcion comun.

Comment: Podrias dar dos pasos atras y agregar un esquema de cual es el objetivo de este modulo y asi sugerir una estructura con un mejor analisis.

Comment: Si no te entendi mal, lo que necesitarias seria usar el patron de diseño  `cadena de responsabilidades`, para no tener que hacer muchos switch.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas... voy a estudiar esas opciones que me habeis dicho... especialmente esos patrones de diseño... hace un mes no los conocia y ya he usado dos o tres en mi proyesto y me han resuelto muchisimo la vida... De echo ha sido un cambio radical...  ese de cadenas de responsabilidades aún no lo conozco. Voy a informarme!! Saludos!!